# How to display arrows based on sorting asc/desc (RoR 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

as the title says, I'm trying to display up/down arrows.  Currently building on Ruby 2.0 / Rails 4.0

I've followed the railscasts about sorting table columns (http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns) but of course he uses tables so his arrows get displayed nicely.

I want to use divs/spans/whatever else. (It's not a lot of data, and it's not the kind of data that needs to be in a table.)

That being said, I went to make an application-helper method for my arrows, and they work, but if I click on one for asc, both arrows point up. If I click one for desc, both point down.  Obviously because the `params[:direction]` is set to asc or desc, both arrows get set.  How do I separate them?  In somewhat pseudocode:

```
if title && asc
  sort by title and asc && show up arrow (for title only)
if title && desc
  sort by title and desc && show down arrow (for title only)
if date posted && asc
  sort by created_by and asc && show up arrow (for date posted only)
etc.
```

I really don't want to have a giant if/then conditionals statement, but would like something simpler.

(If push comes to shove, I'll just use a table for the Sort by: section, but that just seems really awfully silly and that's a bit last resort...)

Here is the code I've got:

**show.html.erb**

```
<h3>Images</h3>
<% if @user.images.any? %>
  <div class="sortable"><%= sortable "img_name", "Title" %><%= arrow %> | 
                        <%= sortable "created_at", "Date posted" %><%= arrow %>
  </div>  
  <%= render @images %>
  <%= will_paginate @images %>
<% end %>
```

**application_helper.rb**

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)
    title ||=  column.titleize
    css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
    direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
    link_to title, {sort: column, direction:  direction}, {class: css_class} 
end

def arrow
    if params[:direction] == 'asc'
        image_tag("arrow_up.png", alt: "up arrow", size: "15x15")
    elsif params[:direction] == 'desc'
        image_tag("arrow_down.png", alt: "down arrow", size: "15x15")
    else
        # either a blank image to show or just force no-display of image
    end
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @images = @user.images.paginate(page: params[:page]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
end
private
  def sort_column
    Image.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "created_at"
  end

  def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not understanding your reluctance to use a table here. Even if it's a small table, this *is* still tabular data, with rows, cols, and headers.  Why replace a semantic table structure with a *table-like* div structure?

That being said, I'd extend the arrow helper to send which column the arrow is for:

```
def arrow(column)
  # as you're not sorting on the column, you don't want to see the arrow at
  # all of the header is not for the sorted column
  return '' if params[:sort] != column
  # ...
end
```

Resulting in the template looking like:

```
<%= sortable "img_name", "Title" %><%= arrow "img_name" %>
```

Although you'll note some unnecessary repetition here.  Since these two helpers are always called together they may as well be joined:

```
def sortable(column, title=nil)
  # ...
  capture do
    concat link_to(title, {...})
    concat " "
    concat arrow(column)
  end
end
```

Resulting in the simpler template:

```
<%= sortable "img_name", "Title" %>
```

Comment: Hm, I tried this, and didn't work. Both arrows were still pointing up or down at the same time.  I've decided to just make a table for the sorting links and try to get it to work that way. :\  Once I get it fully working, I'll post up my solution.

Comment: I think you must have missed something (or I'm missing something).  Note the first line in my arrow helper. There should only be one arrow, the arrow of the column currently being sorted.  If the column is not the column being sorted it returns an empty string instead of an image tag.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else would want to use glyphicon instead of image like myself, this solution might be useful. In this example I'm using [FontAwesome](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/)

**application_helper.rb**

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)
  title ||= column.titleize
  css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
  direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc'

  capture do
    link_to({sort: column, direction: direction}, {class: css_class}) do
      concat title
      concat " "
      concat arrow(column)
    end
  end
end

def arrow(column)
  return '' if params[:sort] != column
  arrow = params[:direction] == 'asc' ? 'down' : 'up'
  "<i class='fa fa-caret-#{arrow}'></i>".html_safe
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= sortable "img_name", "Title" %>
```